# Ошибка "undefined reference to" при попытке использовать функции класса в теле main

Tags: c++, c++11

Код файла man.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <wchar.h>
using namespace std;
class Man
{
    private:
        wstring manName;
        wstring manSex;
        int manAge;

    public:
        Man(wstring, wstring, int);
        void setName(wstring);
        void setSex(wstring);
        void setAge(int);
        void about();
        wstring name();
        wstring sex();
        int age();
};
```

Код файла man.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <wchar.h>
#include "man.h"
using namespace std;
Man::Man(wstring name, wstring sex, int age)
{
    Man::setName(name);
    Man::setSex(sex);
    Man::setAge(age);
}
void Man::about()
{
    wcout
        << L"Name: " << Man::manName << L';' << endl
        << L"Sex: " << Man::manSex << L';' << endl
        << L"Age: " << Man::manAge << L';' << endl;
}
void Man::setName(wstring set_name)
{
    Man::manName = set_name;
}
void Man::setSex(wstring set_sex)
{
    Man::manSex = set_sex;
}
void Man::setAge(int set_age)
{
    Man::manAge = set_age;
}
wstring Man::name()
{
    return Man::manName;
}
wstring Man::sex()
{
    return Man::manSex;
}
int Man::age()
{
    return Man::manAge;
}
```

Код файла main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <wchar.h>
#include "man.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    Man me(L"Dmitry", L"male", 18);
    me.about();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Явно забыли файл `man.cpp` включить в проект.

Comment: @Harry Именно в главный файл? А как же хедер?

Comment: В **проект**. Или в командной строке указать. Компилятор должен скомпилировать **оба** файла и скомпоновать их вместе.